# Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Canary 3 bug

Tags: android-studio, iguana-ui

[image: xml preview bug]

[image]

After updating from Iguana Canary 2 to 3, it became like this,All xml preview interfaces are displayed in yellow,but what’s displayed on the left is normal.                                       Yellow shows blue.

Comment: Well, it's a beta software, therefore bugs might be around. Giraffe 2022.3 version does not have such problem.